# How to remove all changes on styles that have been made with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

hope you are fine
I just wanted to know if there is a method to reset all the styles that have been altered with js

which appear here in the photo

[image]

and Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's anything automatic. You can remember the old styles before making changes in a variable, and use that.

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to toggle classes with JS not add them explicitly.

Comment: If in style attribute are only styles added with script you can simply remove style attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to unset all inline CSS? Try to use

```
document.querySelector("#elementid").style = "";
```

Because CSS added with JS is just inline style. These from external CSS sheets or  tags would be preserved.

Also maybe think about adding a class to your element with JS using

```
element.classList.add("class");
```

and then removing when you need it using

```
element.classList.remove("class");
```

instead of adding new inline styles with

```
document.querySelector("#elementid").style = "some styles";
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your first trick and it worked successfully.
thank you very much.